# Displaying course content from where you left

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, spring, maven

I have stored course (in html format) generated by lectora. I wan't to display the course content from where user has left previously.I am using iframe to load the content.

Comment: Please add some code, so it will help to understand your question

Comment: Per user? where are you storing the last location the client viewed this? You can't modify iframes. You can modify the container but not the content inside it.

Comment: Yes , i wan't to store user wise data according course . But i don't know how should i track and store last viewed page by each user ? I can't modify course generated by lectora. Can we resume course in html format? Thanks in advance